# Help with Mesh Intersection/character self collision

Tags: mesh, collision, intersection

I know this issue has to do with weight painting but she's already weight painted so I don't really understand how to use that to solve this? It happens with the whole body in general when she moves.

I've also dabbled with using collision objects but those don't seem to be much help - and I don't want to have to add them each time I need to make another animation.

A once off whole body solution would be great.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: How did you realize it has to do with weight painting? Please share those infos and your effort to understand the problem. Best would be to share the blend file, see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi - My question was edited (not by me, idk) - but in my original question I explain that I'm just starting out with blender. Some of the suggested solutions were weight painting the affected areas, and using collisions but these are not really solving the problem. Here's the file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bPkNBAnD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bPkNBAnD/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a mesh intersecting with itself shouldn't be a weight painting issues, rather than an issue with the animation itself. I assume the character has a rig, I would recommend editing the animation and moving her hand outside of her head. I'm not sure outside of that what it is that you could be asking.

-----Update----
So I looked at your file, and you've got your work cut out for you. I would recommend setting up an IK rig before doing animations because it will make your workflow much easier. But you need to set your bones to show up as "In front" to allow you to make easier bone selections (recommendation). Being that you have so many keyframes you will have to do a lot of adjusting to make it look the way you want it. I just redid a little bit of the animation adjusting only her Right arm using three bones to prevent your problem from happening. Making small adjustments throughout multiple keyframes to make sure her hand didn't phase through her skull. You can do this for any body part that phases through her body. You can save your adjustments by hitting "i" and choosing location, rotation, and scale, or you can make sure auto key is on in the timeline bar.
[image: AutoKeyInFront]
[image: AdjustmentA]
[image: AdjustmentB]
[image: AdjustmentC]
[image: AdjustmentD]

Comment: Yes, it does have a rig. I want to know to prevent limbs moving into each other with the various motions, so it looks more natural.

Comment: Did you make he animations with that character or did you import them onto the rig serperately

Comment: What you need to do is adjust the frames where the hand is going through the body with the armature and replacing those keyframes. You just need to edit the animation. if you send me the file I can make a short video for you on how to fix it

Comment: nvm I see the file, you should add that in your question next time so we dont miss it

Comment: Thats a lot of keyframes, this will take a minute to fix

Comment: Im gonna update my answer for you.

Comment: If you want help making a an easier to use rig, let me know :) hope you can fix your animation now!

Comment: Okay I understand. As for the rig, I tried using Riggify but her body deformed weird and stiffened up instead and so I just kept the basic one, but I'lll be glad for any help to make this learning curve easier! Thank you so much for your taking the time to help, this means a lot.

Comment: For sure do you have discord? you can add me and we can screen share and Ill show you how to add IK to the rig and get that weight painting just right! Discord took away the numbers some Im pretty sure my username is just RikkaVRM. add me and let me know